# Comment dire en français « You go to your church and I'll go to mine. » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes

Comment pourrait-on rendre cet [adage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adage) en français ?

- You go to your church and I'll go to mine.

Cette formule, apparemment d'origine américaine,  est parfois utilisée par des américains pour exprimer le fait qu'une situation en est arrivé à un point où elle ne peut pas évoluer, aucun des protagonistes ne pouvant se rallier au point de vue d'un autre, et qu'en vertu d'un contexte  donné chacun pourra aller sa route.

Bien sûr, la source de cette expression est le domaine de la religion, et le contexte dans ce domaine c'est le contexte  de la liberté totale de pratiquer n'importe quelle religion, lequel a beaucoup d'importance aux ÉUA.
Dans son sens figuré le contexte  peut ne pas être très explicite ou même être le plus général possible, c'est à dire celui du principe des libertés individuelles.

Trouve-t-on un adage en français qui exprime la même chose ? À défaut d'une forme idiomatique comment exprimer le contenu de cet adage ?

Comment: En quoi les expressions : « à chacun sa paroisse », « prêcher pour sa paroisse », « à chacun sa chapelle » ([e.g.](https://www.cer.eu/in-the-press/au-parlement-n%C3%A9erlandais-chacun-sa-chapelle)) etc., que tu connais forcément, ne te conviennent pas ?

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous J'aurais pu ne pas y penser mais c'est que je ne les connait pas du tout, aucune des trois ; il y a donc des termes idiomatiques qui correspondent exactement. Pourquoi ne pas faire de ce commentaire une réponse normale ?

Comment: Que penses-tu de : « chacun chez soi et les vaches seront bien gardées »?

Comment: @Toto ce n'est pas tout à fait le même sens, et pas le même registre non plus.

Comment: Il serait intéressant de savoir d'où nous vient « à chacun sa chapelle ».

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous: Certes, mais cela indique tout de même que la discussion est inutile entre deux parties.

Comment: @LPH Je croyais que ces expressions été très connues... désolée pour le « que tu connais forcément ». Pour le reste,  comme je l'ai déjà dit en un autre lieu, je ne fais plus de réponses tellement le site s'est éloigné de sa fonction première, c'est devenu un lieu où il ne fait plus bon être. Je continuerai à aider à la modération commune (votes et signalement) et à renseigner les gens, et peut-être pas pour longtemps...

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Je ne lis plus beaucoup, alors des choses même très connues doivent nécessairement   manquer dans mes connaissances.

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait une origine spécifique connue à ces expressions, par contre il me semble qu'elles ne sont toutes attestées que depuis le 19e s. Le dic. de l'Académie atteste « prêcher pour sa paroisse » en 1835. Je pense qu'il en est de même pour *You go to your church and I'll go to mine* auquel je ne vois pas d'origine spécifique connue. If you don't want leave religion entirely out if it you can say *je suis ma route et toi la tienne" but you have that in English as well "You follow your path, I'll follow mine", so....

Comment: Un autre expression - proche mais pas tout à fait équivalent cependant, et sans allusion à la religion - est « voir midi à sa porte » (c.à.d. voir les choses à sa façon), probablement plus ancienne. [Origine](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/origines/l-origine-de-ces-fameuses-expressions-voir-midi-a-sa-porte/)

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous J'ai appris celle-là tout jeune ; détails étymologiques intéressants. C'est une expression qui rime avec l'original anglais mais il manque l'idée de « on ne peut pas continuer » avant celle de « mais on est libre de rester sur nos opinion, de faire selon notre propre intérêt », qui je crois est à peu près tout ce que l'on puisse faire dire à « chacun voit midi à sa porte ».

Comment: "Chacun prêche pour sa chapelle", dit-on chez moi, du côté de Nantes.

Comment: Just as you hadn't heard of its French versions mentioned by @laure , I'm not familiar with the  English "adage" at issue. There is a blue grass/gospel song with that title but the lyrics, for me at least, are more of a confirmation that there are multiple (successful) ways to get somewhere (heaven, in this case) and less of a way to say "let's agree to disagree."

Answer (score 2):

"Chacun voit midi à sa porte" est un proverbe français.

Comment: Il me semble que ce proverbe n'est pas tout à fait ce qu'il faut : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40485/comment-dire-en-fran%c3%a7ais-you-go-to-your-church-and-ill-go-to-mine/40518#comment81508_40485